# Is there a way to automatically display the username on the Desktop background in Win7?

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization

We have computer used by multiple users running Win7. Unfortunately, people forget to log out, or they just use the session that is currently open, or they think that they're using their own session, but in the meantime, somebody else has logged on without logging out.

To make it clear to people that they're using somebody else's session, I'd like to display the username of the person logged on (the one that's visible in the start menu) on the Desktop wallpaper; something like "John Doe's session". Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BgInfo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897557) from Sysinternals would be a pretty easy way to do this. Download it, unzip it somewhere that you'll remember and run it. The first time you'll need to accept the license and do a bit of configuring. You might delete all of the default stuff *except* for username.
Then do a File -> Save As and give your configuration a name (you might save that configuration file in the same directory that you put bginfo.exe)

Now add bginfo as a shortcut to All Users Programs Startup Folder. Edit the shortcut to call your config file. For example:

```
c:\util\bginfo.exe showuser.bgi /timer:0
```